# OpenCV (3.4.18) : error: (-215:Assertion failed) _minSize.size() == _maxSize.size() in function 'PriorBoxLayerImpl'

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV TextDetectorCNN throw Assertion Error, I am using the following code

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("scenetext01.jpg")

det = cv2.text.TextDetectorCNN.create("textbox.prototxt", "TextBoxes_icdar13.caffemodel")

rects, probs = det.detect(img)
```

**Error:**

> error: OpenCV(3.4.18) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/prior_box_layer.cpp:206: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _minSize.size() == _maxSize.size() in function 'PriorBoxLayerImpl'

**With this Test Image:**
[image]

It's supposed to be working got it from [this](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/OpenCV-3-Computer-Vision-with-Python-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter04/14%20Recognize%20text%20in%20natural%20scenes.ipynb) tutorial, What should be the reason for the error.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used that code. But check the reading of your input. Check the shape. Is it zero or null? Do you have the correct path to the image?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct `img.shape` prints `(600, 800, 3)`